# Desktop Fonts are messed up, "Appearance & Personalization" CP is BLANK when I open it and try to restore

Tags: desktop

I tried to rename a file on my desktop, and the text I pasted in apparently contained some disallowed special characters. When I did that, the fonts of ALL folders / files / icons on the desktop got changed to a nearly illegible alternative.

Restart does not help.

When I try to open "Appearance & Personalization" as suggested elsewhere to restore the default settings, the window opens, but it is BLANK -- I cannot select or change anything, because there appears to be nothing there -- no options to select, no buttons to click -- nothing, just an empty window.

If I open other folders, everything appears fine in all views, so it's only the Desktop itself that is messed up.

I am fine restoring pre-set defaults.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The *Desktop* folder in Windows [you don't state OS] is at `C:\Users\<user name>\Desktop`, by default, where <user name> is your user (log on) name.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to open *Explorer*.
- Navigate to the *Desktop* folder.
- Click on the offending file.
- Rename it by pressing<kbd>F2</kbd>.

If that doesn't work, [use the command prompt to rename it](https://www.windows-commandline.com/rename-file-from-command-line/):

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cmd` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the CMD prompt.
- Type `cd C:\Users\<user name>\Desktop` to change to the *Desktop* folder.
- Rename it by typing `rename <first few chars>*.<ext> <newname>.<ext>`, where  are the first few characters of the bad file, before the illegal character, and  is the file extension.